# Are those bowls genuine LEGO pieces?

Tags: part-identification

I've been sieving through my video collection and came across a video from 2011. It's part of a series of Ninjago videos giving you tips on fun things you could do with the Spinners. At the end of the video, there's this frame where Cole goes to a laid out dinner table to eat with the other Ninjas:
[image]

I find this scene rather adorable, but find it slightly puzzling; for starters, how are those tiles connected to each other? But that's not really my question; you don't really need to answer that. My real question is, are those 6 bowls real LEGO pieces? They look rather peculiar and Un-LEGO-y. I get how they made the cups and bottles; they just flipped some 1x1 round bricks and a chalice. But how about those bowls? If it is a real piece, could someone direct me to a set containing it, and if not, what they might be?

Comment: Fwiw, the plate(s) underneath the table, holding it together, would be obscured by Zane (in white) here.

Answer (score 11):

My guess is that they're LEGO Round Plate 1 x 1 Straight Side (Part ID: 4569058
Design ID: 6141) with paint applied to make them look like food. Details of some of the sets that contain them are available on [BrickLink](http://www.brickset.com/parts/?part=4216581).

[image: LEGO Round Plate 1 x 1]

Comment: That's what it looked like to me as well.

Comment: Really? I feel like the top is a bit too smooth, and there's a slight curve between the lip and the top and the lip to the bottom that kind of smooths it out. Plus, I find it slightly unlikely for designers to tamper with official bricks. But yeah, currently this is the most plausible answer, but I'll stick around for other opinions first.

Comment: If someone is going to paint a LEGO brick to suit them I wouldn't be surprised if they sanded down the lettering too.

Answer (score 11):

I also think those parts are painted, but I would like to add one more thing. The LEGO Friends sets have these cute cupcake holders that are quite similar, and no painting is required. They come in four colors, and you can easily insert a 1x1 round tile inside to add the "food". Here is the link: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=93082g

And here is a picture so you get an idea how they look like (on your left, right on top of the display cooler):

[image]

Comment: Yes, my sister actually bought this set recently so I've got a good idea of how they look. However, that's doesn't quite answer the question...But yes, I admit they're quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, they are most likely studs. The cupcake holders have only been made in yellow, though that picture could be explained as custom paintwork. However, please notice how the ''sushi rolls'' in the picture have no ridges, whereas the cupcake holders from the Friends bakery set do.

Comment: [Cupcake holders come in 4 colors, btw.](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93082g&name=Friends%20Accessories%20Cupcake%20Holder&category=%5BFriends%5D)